# Dynamically adding optgroup list

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-select2

I am trying to get the jQuery plugin select2 to update dynamically using json

JSON 'optionString':

```
[{"text":"A","children":[{"id":"313","name":"Adair, Graham"}]},{"text":"B","children":[{"id":"396","name":"Boots, Benjamin"}]},{"text":"M","children":[{"id":"616","name":"Marshall, James"},{"id":"361","name":"Montgomery, Kirsty"}]}]
```

and the select2 javascript:

```
var names = jQuery.parseJSON(optionString);

function format(item) { return item.name; };
$("#nameSearchSel").select2({
        placeholder: "Name Search",
        data:{ results: names, text: 'name' },
        formatSelection: format,
        formatResult: format,
});
```

HTML:

```
<input id="nameSearchSel" type="hidden" style="width:190px;"/>
```

This updates the select2 but strips out all the optgroups.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Solved it...

Changed this in the JSON ('name' to 'text'):

```
[{"text":"A","children":[{"id":"313","text":"Adair, Graham"}]},{"text":"B","children":[{"id":"396","text":"Boots, Benjamin"}]},{"text":"M","children":[{"id":"616","text":"Marshall, James"},{"id":"361","text":"Montgomery, Kirsty"}]}]
```

And this in the javascript ('name' to 'text'):

```
var names = jQuery.parseJSON(optionString);

function format(item) { return item.text; };
$("#nameSearchSel").select2({
        placeholder: "Name Search",
        data:{ results: names, text: 'text' },
        formatSelection: format,
        formatResult: format,
});
```